# Randomize/Shuffle Div elements containing iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have a video page displaying youtube videos that some of our customers have made, but I would like them to shuffle/randomize on page load. I tried a few scripts from around the web, but to no avail. Did not include css as i don't believe it's relevant, but if it is just let me know. Thank you

```js
// This script is one of the ones i found online somewhere
$(function() {
  var parent = $(".video-page-wrap");
  var divs = parent.children();
  while (divs.length) {
    parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-page-wrap d-flex">

  <div class="flex-fill video-container">
    <iframe loading="lazy" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aMxWn63mEWc" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-fill video-container">
    <iframe loading="lazy" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HLIrLLqpACE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-fill video-container">
    <iframe loading="lazy" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eH61UnQDq1k" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-fill video-container">
    <iframe loading="lazy" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/K1so5z8CzOM" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-fill video-container">
    <iframe loading="lazy" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KWGx5WKtJpo" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-fill video-container">
    <iframe loading="lazy" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E2-tZsr3FKE" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-fill video-container">
    <iframe loading="lazy" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8ib4b-ie29Y" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-fill video-container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/J9_lAcsFCwQ" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-fill video-container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bSUezxWuRCk" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-fill video-container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aRCHbJPqfBU" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-fill video-container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KNDWQALC0RA" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-fill video-container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BWgLAXamLS8" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: define "to no avail"

Comment: = does not function how it should